# Browser using cached JavaScript assets despite them being modified in Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I've just upgraded my application to Rails 3.1. I have a fairly complex JavaScript codebase and have opted to concatenate it into a single .js.coffee file to be compiled by Sprockets. Every so often, I'll make changes to one of my CoffeeScript files, refresh the page, and notice my changes weren't reflected. Looking at the Chrome debugger, I notice the files aren't being read from the server (the 'Network' tab shows '(from cache)' on the corresponding files). This seems to happen at random, which makes it very, very frustrating to develop. The only solutions I've found are to clear the browser cache or restart the browser.

Any ideas? I've tried turning :debug on in my javascript_include_tag calls, but was getting the same results. In fact, when I had multiple  tags, it seemed that the only assets returning '(from cache)' were those I had changed! That's some irony right there.

Comment: Did you try holding `shift` and hitting reload? I believe this should reload the page without hitting the cache.

Comment: Still a problem with Chrome 19 and Rails 3.2. Even though the cache control headers includes must-revalidate, the page is served from the cache (sometimes).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome offers an option to disable caching in it's developer tools. Go to Settings, and under Network, there should be a checkbox to disable cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate. I just created a new Rails 3.1 project, then did

```
rails generate controller welcome index
```

deleted `index.html`, uncommented

```
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

from `routes.rb`, added the line

```
console.log 1
```

to `welcome.js.coffee`, then fired up Chrome and loaded `http://0.0.0.0:3000/`. I got `1` on the console. Changed the number to `2`, saved, refreshed the page, and got `2`. And so on. Doesn't seem to matter whether I hit Cmd+R or just type type in the address; either way I get the latest `welcome.js` served to me.

Could you "view source" for me? Does your script include look like

```
<script src="/assets/welcome.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or is it different?

Comment: Yeah, it's as you've specified. The issue only occurs occasionally, but when it hits, it's downright annoying. For the time being, I've been using hard refresh in my browser (Shift+Cmd+R) to force reload all cached resources and it seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: @Teejay Huh. So is it possible that your project is doing anything that would cause assets to be cached (that is, for the server to give a "304 Not Modified" when a file is requested)? Anything in your Gemfile that might have that effect?